# netplan.io WEP secured WiFi

Tags: wireless, raspberrypi, netplan

I have to connect my raspberry pi3+ to an WEP "secured" WiFi. I searched the netplan.io website but couldn't find an configuration example fitting my use case. Is netplan even supporting WEP configurations?
Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

The syntax is the same as for connecting to a WPA personal network: https://netplan.io/examples#connecting-to-a-wpa-personal-wireless-network

This isn't documented separately because WEP itself is deprecated and insecure.

Comment: First thank you for the reply! I am aware that WEP is insecure, but in this special scenario it is given like that. 

Are you sure it is possible to configure the connection like that?
Because I now have a working configuration that looks like this in wpa_supplicant:
`network={
ssid="SSID_OF_ROUTER"
key_mgmt=NONE
wep_key0="******"
wep_tx_keyidx=0
}`

And a config generated like you suggest looks like this:
`ctrl_interface=/run/wpa_supplicant

network={
  ssid="SSID_OF_ROUTER"
  key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
  psk="******"
}`

Comment: can you try with auth: key-management: none as part of the ssid config?

Comment: Unfortunately setting  `auth: key-management: none` doesn't work

Comment: It is not documented *at all*, and it is certainly not the same.  How for instance is a hex key distinguished? How are keys enumerated? This is a useless and vexatious answer. No WiFi is secure, and there are mitigations for WEP.